# How to solve the problem that can't select project using Omni Sharp on VS Core?

Tags: select, project, omnisharp

When I use the Omni Sharp to choose a project on VS Code, it occurs an error as follow:

```
 Command 'OmniSharp: Select Project' resulted in an error (Extension 'ms-dotnettools.csharp'CANNOT use API proposal: quickPickSeparators. 
lts packagejson#enabledApiProposals-property declares: [] but NOT quickPickSeparators.The missing proposal MUST be added and you must start in extension development mode or use the following command line switch:--enable-proposed-api ms-dotnettools.csharp)
```

[image]

How can I fix the error?

Comment: This problem occurs when I update the version of VS Code from 1.62 to 1.63, and has been fixed after the VS Code is rolled back to 1.62

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you already found this ticket?

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4907

This must be caused by a bug related to the OmniSharp extension.
For the moment, you can either down grade VS code to 1.62 or try to use pre release version of the extension mentioned in the ticket.

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.23.18-beta2

Please note that you can install the downloaded vsix file inside VS code.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_install-from-a-vsix

Comment: I tested the **v1.24.0-beta1**: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.24.0-beta1 - it works too :)

Comment: thanks, the visx can also solve the problem